# CURL extension needs to be loaded - Opencart on WAMP 3.0.0

Tags: php, curl, wamp, opencart

I have been trying to install opencart 2.1.0.2 on WAMP 3.0.0 but I keep getting the error message "Warning: CURL extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work! ", When I navigate to C:\wamp64\bin\php I notice there are two php folders here php5.6.16 and php7.0.0, although on my localhost page it says that the current php setting is php5.6.16. I did a CURL search inside my php.ini file (in the php5.6.16 folder) and I found the following string of codes

```
; Note that ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
; Note that many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) ext/ (PHP 5)
; extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5).
; Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
```

I need some help here, how do I turn on / load CURL?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are several `php.ini` files. You need to find the one that is loaded at run time.

1. Create a new PHP file and echo your loaded PHP configuration: `echo phpinfo();`
2. Search if you can find a section dedicated for CURL.
3. If not, find the section `Loaded Configuration File`to see which php.ini file is being loaded.
4. Add `extension=php_curl.dll`to the loaded `php.ini` file.
5. Restart Apache.

Comment: The one that is loaded to run is the php.ini file inside the php5.6.16 folder, where exactly do I add     extension=php_curl.dll  ?

Comment: The position does not matter, if it is there, restart Apache and check your PHPinfo. It should be there.

Comment: extension=php_curl.dll is already in both php.ini files, I don't get why it's not working. Can you explain how I can find the php.ini loaded at run time? I am new to all this.

Comment: Have you done step one? Create a new file and add the following code: `<?php echo phpinfo();`. Execute the file in your browser and then paste me the `Loaded Configuration File`path.

Answer (score 0):

Using the WAMPServer menus is the easiest way and ensured that you amend the correct `php.ini` file as there are 2 versions, one for Apache/PHP and one for PHP CLI. It will also make sure you amend the correct `php.ini` file for the version of PHP that is actually active when you make the amendment, remember WAMPServer can have multiple versions of Apache & PHP and MYSQL sitting on the system, but only one of each active.

```
(left click) wampmanager -> PHP -> PHP Extensions -> php_curl
```

Also if you are using a https address in your curl you will likely need to also include php_openssl

```
(left click) wampmanager -> PHP -> PHP Extensions -> php_openssl
```

If these items have a TICK beside them then they are already activated, if no tick then click the menu item, the php.ini file will automatically be amended and Apache restarted. You will see the wampmanager icon go Orange and then Green again when the amendment is complete and Apache restarted.